# Jupyter Notebook/Pandas not reading excel file after moving ipynb

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on automating some reporting for work which starts off with a pd.read_excel method. It worked fine and I moved on with the rest of my code. When I was done, I had a few ipynb files on my desktop and moved them into a folder called "Python". After doing so, I'm getting a "No such file or directory" error when rerunning the code. The file is in a folder called "Reporting". I can leave them on the desktop for now, but typically have everything organized in folders to avoid clutter. What do I need to do to get my code to continue read in the excel files?

```
    RawData=pd.read_excel("Reporting/LS_Questions.xlsx",skiprows=2)
```

Comment: Well you've got a relative path there, if you move stuff around that's very likely to break. Try putting the absolute path to the excel file instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an absolute path rather than a relative path.
Right now your path assumes that the file is within the same directory as the notebook.
you can either:

1. use a full path a.i - "C:\User{user_name}\Desktop\LS_Questions.xlsx"
2. Move the CSV/XL file to the directory of the notebook.